# Tabulating data from table using COUNT, AVG and Having in one sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle developer. I have a requirement where I'm to tabulate data on these conditions.

1. How Many times the books has been borrowed
2. What is the average borrow duration
3. Who is its favorite reader. (what if have two person as the favourite reader?)

I have the borrower table.

```
EMPLID    BOOK_ID       BORROW_DT   RETURN_DT 
---------------------------------------------
00000058    6           17-JUL-14   31-JUL-14
00000015    6           17-JUL-14   31-JUL-14
00000001    1           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000004    1           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000009    5           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000010    5           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000044    5           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000002    1           15-JUL-14   15-JUL-14
00000008    1           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000014    1           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000007    5           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000003    1           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000004    5           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000006    1           15-JUL-14   15-JUL-14
00000009    1           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000009    2           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000010    1           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000010    2           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000011    1           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000011    2           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000012    2           15-JUL-14   15-JUL-14
00000044    1           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000003    2           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000004    2           16-JUL-14   30-JUL-14
00000001    2           14-JUL-14   14-JUL-14
00000001    1           14-JUL-14   14-JUL-14
00000001    5           14-JUL-14   28-JUL-14
00000005    2           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000007    2           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000007    1           15-JUL-14   17-JUL-14
00000008    2           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000008    5           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000013    2           15-JUL-14   29-JUL-14
00000011    2           17-JUL-14   31-JUL-14
```

Based on the requirement I have the sql statement.

```
select DISTINCT 
    xyz_book_id_f, 
    count(book_id), 
    TRUNC(sum(RETURN_DT - BORROW_DT)/ count(book_id), 2) as AverageDuration,
    emplid 
from ps_xyz_borrow09 
group by book_id,emplid  
having count (book_id) > 1;
```

The results is

```
BOOK_ID   COUNT(BOOK_ID)  AVERAGEDURATION       EMPLID
-------------------------------------------------------
1          2                7                  00000001
2          2                14                 00000009
2          2                14                 00000011
```

It doesnt show book_id that do not have a favourite reader.
I have Book_ID:1,2,5,6. So I want to show all the book ids regardless if the book_id have no favourite reader.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF GOD STOP SHOUTING!

Comment: What is "peoplecode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct.  It is at the `book_id`/`emplid` level rather than at the book level.  You can get what you want as:

```
select xyz_book_id_f, count(book_id) as NumTimesBorrowed, 
       TRUNC(avg(RETURN_DT - BORROW_DT), 2) as AverageDuration,
       stats_mode(emplid) as MostCommonBorrower
from ps_xyz_borrow09 
group by book_id;
```

Notes about this query:

- It removes `select distinct`.  That is almost never needed with a `group by` query.
- It only aggregates by `book_id`, because that is the level for the results.
- It uses the `avg()` function, which is more convenient than a sum divided by a count.
- It uses `stats_mode()` to get the most common value (or one of several equivalent modes).  The most common value is called the "mode" in statistics.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff for the help. It works fine. Your notes are clear too. Appreciate that.